# Invoking function in project A from project B without references

Tags: c#, invoke, multi-project

I change my post because the last one was unclear.
Is it possible to call function in project A from project B (in the same solution of course) without creating a reference?

I found this article: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13747/Dynamically-load-a-class-and-execute-a-method-in-N but I need to call function from project, not dll file.

Best regards

Comment: It's unclear why Server needs a reference to Platform at all - it sounds like it's all about Platform calling Server rather than the other way round...

Comment: Yes, why doesn't Platform just call Server and wait for it to return the result?

Answer (score 1):

When I've written WCF applications before, there's two approaches I've taken:

1) Recreate the types in the client project by linking to the same "source file" (useful for things like Silverlight clients).
2) Use a third project to host the shared types.